# Qt WheelEvent, how to get if the wheel is pressed?

Tags: c++, qt

i'm developing a Qt application, I know that there is a wheelEvent to get the wheel's state, but I can't find how to know if the wheel is pressed.
thanks !

Comment: wheel press should be 3rd button press...

Comment: oh ok, i thought it was handled by the WheelEvent, thanks

Answer (score 3):

The wheel event set up the [buttons which are being pressed](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwheelevent.html#buttons). It also set the keyboard modifier keys which are pressed (eg. `SHIFT`, `CRTL`).

```
void MyWidget::wheelEvent ( QWheelEvent * event )
{
  if(event->buttons() & Qt::MiddleButton != 0)
  {
    //the mid button is being pressed. handle.
  }
}
```

[Here is a list of possible buttons](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#MouseButton-enum). They are set as flags, i.e `Qt::LeftButton | Qt::RightButton`

**Edit:** 
The wheel is associated by default to the middle button. The wheel can move without an associated button in the wheel event. For instance, on chrome browsers moving the wheel scrolls. Pressing the wheel will change the cursor on the screen as well as the behavior of the wheel(try it).

If you have a weird mouse with a wheel and a middle button:

- Pressing the middle button will generate a `MouseEvent` with `Qt::MiddleButton`
- Pressing the wheel button will generate a `WheelEvent` with `Qt::MiddleButton`.

Comment: what does `Qt::MiddleButton` return ?? I don't understand this expression : `event->buttons() && Qt::MiddleButton`, i'm not used to c++ yet ...

Comment: `Qt::MiddleButton` is a value. but I made a mistake, it is `&` rather than `&&`

Comment: yes I see that it's value is 4, but how why use it as a boolean ? it would always returns true, your answer is working but if it was something like this : `if(event->button == Qt::MiddleButton)` it would have been logical

Comment: both way works in c++. but I edited with a more explicit version.

Comment: I just don't understand how `event->buttons()` which returns the state of the buttons and `Qt::MiddleButton` that is equal to 4 can return a boolean if the MiddleButton is pressed or not

Comment: does the value of Qt::MiddleButton change ?

Comment: why should it? It would break thousands of applications.

Comment: So why add `Qt::MiddleButton != 0` ?? this would have always the same value ( true ), so this `event->buttons() & Qt::MiddleButton != 0`would have the same value as this `event->buttons()` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59359/discussion-between-user3883676-and-umnyobe).

Comment: @user3883676 sorry but I am at work. others button can be pressed as well. in this case `event->buttons()` will contain more than one button. If you have another question post a new one.

Comment: @user3883676 There is an error in his code. It should be `if((event->buttons() & Qt::MiddleButton) != 0)`. The reason for the extra parentheses is explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Criticism_of_bitwise_and_equality_operators_precedence).

Comment: Hmmmm, not working here. I do get the QWheelEvent (when I scroll it I output some stuff in the terminal) but the clicking doesn't work (at least in Qt for some reason).

Comment: Never mind. I was handling it like a wheel even but it actually is a mouse press event. **facepalm**

Answer (score 0):

Look in the documentation of QMouseEvent. Catch that event and watch out for the third mouse button.

If you are not interested in an event but the state of the button you also may be interested in QGuiApplication::mouseButtons().